# How do you export specific Svelte components as individual classes with specified names?

Tags: components, export, svelte, iife

If you have an existing JS app that doesn't use ESM, CJS, but instead is just a bunch of vanilla JS, how do you export Svelte components to be used from random places in the app? I'd ideally like to have vanilla JS files that look like this:

```
    import AddressComponent from './AddressComponent.svelte';
    import DifferentComponent from './DifferentComponent.svelte';
    // ... my js app code
    const address = new AddressComponent({target: ...});
    // ... more vanilla JS code
    const address = new DifferentComponent({target: ...});
    // ... more vanilla JS code
```

Or even without the imports, which I can manage as a list elsewhere for generating the Svelte components standalone if necessary.

---

Using rollup, it seems the only way things work is by specifying 'iife'. However, this bundles my entire app as an IIFE and breaks a lot of the code renaming things and what not. Seems to be no way around it.

I have gotten nice compiled components using this method [Exporting Separate Custom Elements from Svelte Components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56356230/exporting-separate-custom-elements-from-svelte-components), however that generates esm or cjs svelte components. Possibly there a tool to easily convert this format to vanilla JS? I've searched with no luck

I've used many combos of settings with gulp and rollup together with no success.

Comment: Perhaps you can just copy\paste the svelte's generated JS inside your project, and then create the component using `create_component` from `svelte/internal`, why not give it a try?

Answer (score 0):

The `bundle.js` create by svelte automatically exports the `app` root component to the browser (unless you changes its name),

you can write in your `bundle.js` right before the `return app;` statement the following line:

`app.Child = Child // or whatever your component is called`

Then in your javascript:

`var child = new app.Child({ target: document.body });`

using the props you want.

Your HTML page should eventually look like this:

```
<script src="public/build/bundle.js"></script>
<link href="public/build/bundle.css" rel='stylesheet'></link>
<script>
var child = new app.Child({ target: document.body });
</script>
```